# Converting dctionary loop python in Json

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, telegram

im programming a new telegram bot. I've created a loop which inserts the variable `i` in the dictionari `dic` that describes a new button. But when i convert `dic` in Json dictionary, it gives me this problem.

```
import botogram
import json

bot = botogram.create("1210935912:AAG4X8vHlXLM3jQWnxFKDB2NsZ6pqTQM7lQ")
list = ["La","Alaska","New Delhi"]
bot.about = "Benvenuti"
@bot.command("start")
def start_command(chat, message):
    for i in list:
        dict = {
            'chat_id': chat.id,
            'text': 'Where are you?',
            'reply_markup': {
            'keyboard': [[
                {'text': i},
                {'text': 'Action B'},
            ],
            [
                {
                    'text': 'Use geolocation',
                    'request_location': True,
                },
            ],
        ],
        'resize_keyboard': True,
        'one_time_keyboard': True,
        'selective': True,
        }
    }
    bot.api.call('sendMessage', json.loads(dict))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     bot.run()
```

Output:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Comment: Just use `json.dumps(dict)`.

Answer (score 1):

json is a text representation of a data structure.

`json.loads` converts a json string into a dictionary. Since you already have a dictionary, and want a json string, you should instead use the `json.dumps`method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json.dumps` to convert object to json

```
bot.api.call('sendMessage', json.dumps(dict))
```

Comment: It doesnt work: Request failed with code 400. Response from Telegram: "Bad Request: message text is empty"